# Start Cloudformation stacks in parallel from ansible

Tags: ansible, aws-cloudformation

I am starting multiple cloudformation stacks in a "with_items" loop in ansible like this:

```
- name: Create CF stack in AWS
  cloudformation:
    stack_name: "{{ item.name }}"
    state: "present"
    template: "{{ item.name }}.py.json"
    template_parameters: "{{ item.template_parameters }}"
  with_items: "{{ CF_TEMPLATE_ITEMS }}"
```

Can I somehow make ansible start this stacks in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using asynchronous tasks in a fire-and-forget scheme (and waiting for them to finish in a separate task) should work since ansible 2.0:

```
- name: Create CF stack in AWS
  async: 100
  poll: 0
  cloudformation:
    stack_name: "{{ item.name }}"
    state: "present"
    template: "{{ item.name }}.py.json"
    template_parameters: "{{ item.template_parameters }}"
  with_items: "{{ CF_TEMPLATE_ITEMS }}"
  register: cf_stack_async_results

- async_status:
    jid: "{{item.ansible_job_id}}"
  with_items: cf_stack_async_results.results
  register: cf_stack_async_poll_results
  until: cf_stack_async_poll_results.finished
  retries: 30
```