# running certain ansible tasks in parallel

Tags: ansible

I have a simple ansible playbook where I want the first 3 tasks to run in parallel and then the rest to run after those three are done. I've looked at async but i don't quite understand how it gets implemented.

Right now I have this:

```
---
- name: gkeop
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: adminWsInstall
      vmware_deploy_ovf:
        hostname: '{{ hostname_vcenter }}'
        username: '{{ username }}'
        password: '{{ password }}'
        ...
      delegate_to: localhost
    - name: vcenterInstall
      vmware_deploy_ovf:
        hostname: '{{ hostname_vcenter }}'
        username: '{{ username }}'
        password: '{{ password }}'
        ...
      delegate_to: localhost
    - name: f5Install
      vmware_deploy_ovf:
        hostname: '{{ hostname_vcenter }}'
        username: '{{ username }}'
        password: '{{ password }}'
        ...
      delegate_to: localhost
    - name: Cluster Add
      template:
        src: cluster.sh.j2
        dest: /home//cluster.sh
        mode: 0777
    - name: F5 License
      template:
        src: f5.sh.j2
        dest: /home/f5.sh
        mode: 0777
    - name: Run cluster add
      command: sh /home/cluster.sh
      become: true
    - name: Run f5 license
      command: sh /home/f5.sh
      become: true
```

so do I just add in, for example,

```
async: 600 
poll: 5
```

to each of the three tasks first tasks and that would make them run in parallel?

Comment: maybe this helps: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42223344/start-cloudformation-stacks-in-parallel-from-ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42223344/start-cloudformation-stacks-in-parallel-from-ansible)

Answer (score 2):

the fourth task should check that the other tasks have finished. Look at this sample playbook:

```
- hosts: loc
  tasks:
    - name: sleep 10 seconds
      shell: sleep 10
      async: 10
      poll: 0
      register: sleeper1
    - name: sleep 10 seconds again
      shell: sleep 10
      async: 10
      poll: 0
      register: sleeper2
    - name: sleep 10 seconds again
      shell: sleep 10
      async: 10
      poll: 0
      register: sleeper3
    - name: wait for all 3 tasks
      async_status: jid="{{ item }}"
      register: job_result
      until: job_result.finished
      retries: 10
      with_items:
        - "{{ sleeper1.ansible_job_id }}"
        - "{{ sleeper2.ansible_job_id }}"
        - "{{ sleeper3.ansible_job_id }}"
    - name: next task
      debug:
        msg: "ready"
```

The last task runs only if the others are done. Hope that helps.